# Combining Tasks and Workflows in Liferay Social Office

Tags: java, workflow, liferay, liferay-6

I'm currently testing Liferay 6.1 CE with it's social office plugin. I've managed to create a custom workflow with Kaleo and have a few test users work though it. However, it seems like the "Tasks" panel in Social Office and the "My Workflows" portlet in the control panel are two completely separate entities.

I really like how users are alerted on when they are assigned a task, and would like to have my custom workflows do the same thing. Is this possible? I don't want users to have to check their control panel for workflow requests.

Answer (score 0):

To check the relation between the users you need check the workfolw tasks portlet and workflow instace portlet,although they  one is creator user and one is assignee,which is available in workflow tasks portlet.
To check the user state at each step we can use the workflow logs, which have the complete information.